# Generate PTS/SCR value for MJPEG uvc payload header

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver, uvc

We are working on one UVC driver to stream mjpeg to host applications. We are using simple two bytes uvc frame header without any pts/scr value added to it. code works fine with all the linux based uvc host applications. but for windows based uvc host application lot of frame drops are happening.

I was wondering if anyone has seen this kind of behavior earlier. I am suspecting PTS/SCR value missing in header for frame synchronization.

If that is the case can anyone please give me one simple example how to calculate pts/scr value in host clock frequency units.

any kind of help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause for an issue.

Issue was i wasn't making the requested usb length to 0 when i dont have any data to send to the host. That was creating bug in the flow.

Now it works fine in linux as well as in the windows without any glitches.

Thanks